# How to avoid search trigger on enter when autocomplete is going to be used? ANGULAR HTML

Tags: html, angular, autocomplete, enter

I am trying to have an autocomplete with enter and then be able to search with enter for my input. How can I not trigger the search with enter when an autocomplete should be chosen? At the moment, both are triggered at the same time, already after first chosen autocomplete.

HTML:

```
<input placeholder="Addera kompetenser..." #competenceInput [formControl]="competenceCtrl" [matAutocomplete]="auto" [matChipInputFor]="chipList" [matChipInputSeparatorKeyCodes]="separatorKeysCodes" (keydown.enter)="serachTriggerEnter()" (matChipInputTokenEnd)="add($event)">
```

TS:

```
separatorKeysCodes: number[] = [ENTER];

serachTriggerEnter() {
    this.searchCompetences(); 
}

add(event: MatChipInputEvent): void {
    const value = event.value 
    this.addToArray(value);
    event.chipInput!.clear();
    this.competenceCtrl.setValue(null);
}
```

If you want me to add information to make it easier to understand my question, please do not hesitate to ask me!

Thanks in advance.